# Last three months average for each month in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to build a query in Postgresql that will be used for a budget.

I currently have a list of data that is grouped by month.

For each month of the year I need to retrieve the average monthly sales from the previous three months. For example, in January I would need the average monthly sales from October through December of the previous year. So the result will be something like:

```
1  12345.67
2  54321.56
3  242412.45
```

This is grouped by month number.

Here is a snippet of code from my query that will get me the current month's sales:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM((sti.cost + sti.freight) * sti.case_qty * sti.release_qty)
                  AS trsf_cost,
                  DATE_PART('month', st.invoice_dt) as month
             FROM stransitem sti, 
                  stocktrans st
            WHERE sti.invoice_no = st.invoice_no 
              AND st.invoice_dt >= date_trunc('year', current_date) 
              AND st.location_cd = 'SLC' 
              AND st.order_st != 'DEL'
         GROUP BY month) as trsf_cogs ON trsf_cogs.month = totals.month
```

I need another join that will get me the same thing, only averaged from the previous 3 months, but I'm not sure how.

This will ALWAYS be a January-December (1-12) list, starting with January and ending with December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem for a window function. Here is how to solve this:

```
SELECT month_nr
      ,(COALESCE(m1, 0)
      + COALESCE(m2, 0)
      + COALESCE(m3, 0))
      /
      NULLIF ( CASE WHEN m1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
             + CASE WHEN m2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
             + CASE WHEN m3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 0) AS avg_prev_3_months
      -- or divide by 3 if 3 previous months are guaranteed or you don't care
FROM   (
    SELECT date_part('month', month) as month_nr
          ,lag(trsf_cost, 1) OVER w AS m1
          ,lag(trsf_cost, 2) OVER w AS m2
          ,lag(trsf_cost, 3) OVER w AS m3
    FROM  (
        SELECT date_part( 'month', month) as trsf_cost -- some dummy nr. for demo
                          ,month
        FROM   generate_series('2010-01-01 0:0'::timestamp
                              ,'2012-01-01 0:0'::timestamp, '1 month') month
        ) x
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY month)
    ) y;
```

This is requires that **no month is ever missing**! Else, have a look at this related answer:
[How to compare the current row with next and previous row in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974866/how-to-compare-the-current-row-with-next-and-previous-row-in-postgresql/7975001#7975001)

Calculates correct average for *every month*. If only two previous moths then devide by 2, etc. If no prev. months, result is NULL.

In your subquery, use

```
date_trunc('month', st.invoice_dt)::date AS month
```

instead of

```
DATE_PART('month', st.invoice_dt) as month
```

so you can sort months over the years easily!

#### More info

- Window function [lag()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html)
- [date_trunc()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html)