# Finding missing values from a sequence in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, select

I'm kinda clueless about how to write a strange (at least for me!) SELECT statement. I'm new to SQL and I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do makes sense...
Let's say I have the given table :

```
 ID_NUMBER
 ---------
 1
 2
 3
 5
 6
 8
```

Is there any simple way to have a table returned with the missing values of ID_NUMBER from
the sequence of [1-8] to obtain the following table?

```
 ID_NUMBER
 ---------
 4
 7
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use a 'Numbers' table (also called a tally table)

Comment: You can use WINDOW functions if your database supports it.  Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974866/how-to-compare-the-current-row-with-next-and-previous-row-in-postgresql

Comment: Generally you need to [create a table and do an OUTER JOIN against it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1389605/712765)