# SQL query to report duration untill next log entry

Tags: sql, postgresql, reporting, postgresql-9.2

I'm working with PostgreSql and trying to build reporting query for my logs, but unfortunately unsuccessfully...
Basically I have LOG table which logs status changes of other entity. So for the sake of simplicity lets say it has columns STATUS and STATUS_CHANGE_DATE. Now each status change updates this logging table with new status and time it was changed. What I need is the duration and number of times status in it for each status (same status can be used multiple times, e.g go from status 1 to 2 then back to 1). I would like to build a view for it and use in my java application reporting by mapping that view right to hibernate entity. Unfortunately I'm not that experienced with sql so maybe someone can give me some hints of whats best solution would be as I tried few things but basically don't know how to do it.
Lets say we have:

```
STATUS STATUS_CHANGE_DATE
1      2013 01 01
2      2013 01 03
1      2013 01 06
3      2013 01 07
```

My wanted result would be a table that contains status 1 with 2 times and 3 days duration and status 2 1 time with 3 days duration too (assuming status 3 is end(or close) and its duration is not required).

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide sample results to clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: The simplest solution would be using the `LEAD()` function to calculate spans; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974866/how-to-compare-the-current-row-with-next-and-previous-row-in-postgresql.

Comment: I *think* you're trying to convert a status edge list (records of times when statuses change) into a list of time-ranges when statuses were certain values. Your explanation is pretty hard to follow and there isn't enough clear sample data / expected result info here, so I can't do much more than guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your statuses are changing in every row, you can do this

```
with cte as (
    select
        status,
        lead(status_change_date) over(order by status_change_date) as next_date,
        status_change_date
    from Table1
)
select
    status, count(*) as cnt,
    sum(next_date - status_change_date) as duration
from cte
where next_date is not null
group by status
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7f489/5)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT "STATUS", "STATUS_CHANGE_DATE" - lag("STATUS_CHANGE_DATE") OVER (ORDER BY "STATUS_CHANGE_DATE") AS "DURATION" FROM table ORDER BY "STATUS";
```

This works for me in a similar case, in my case i need to calculate the average time between sessions in a log table. I hope this works for you.