# find the process of a unit that happened before a specific process step

Tags: sql, postgresql

We are using php/postgresql for process control at our company.
The company is repairing units, and the repair process is followed by the process control system.

[image: Database structure]

The unit table stores the information about the individual units.

- unit.id : the id of the unit
- unit.sn : the serial number of the unit

The unit_process table stores every process step the unit went through in it's lifetime.

- unit_process.id : the id of the process step
- unit_process.unit_id : the id of the unit
- unit_process.process_id : the id of the process.

(the real tables have more columns)

an sql to find a unit's process steps in chronological order:

```
SELECT process_id 
FROM unit 
INNER JOIN unit_process on unit.id=unit_process.unit_id
ORDER BY unit_process.id
```

**I would like to create a query which finds all process steps which are happened before process steps that have a specific process_id**

So I have a process_id, I need to find all unit_process rows that happened just before a process which has that process_id

Currently I am using about the worst method I can imagine.

For example let's say, I need all previous process steps which happened before processes that has process_id=17

First, I list the units which have processes with process_id=17

```
SELECT unit.id
FROM unit
INNER JOIN unit_process on unit.id=unit_process.unit_id
WHERE process_id=17
```

Then I store them in a php array.

Secondly, I use a php foreach which contains the following query for every unit id I got from the previous query.

```
SELECT id,process_id
FROM unit_process
WHERE unit_id=$unit_id
ORDER BY id
```

After this, I could easily find out using php what process was before the process_id=17 process step, since I just have to find the biggest id value which is still lower than the (process_id=17)'s.

It could use up to thousands of querys in that foreach, and I want to change that, but I don't have enough SQL knowledge to do it on my own.

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Sample input 
greens are needed, yellows are the process_id=17 units. Notice that there is a process_id=17 wich is also needed :

[image]

Sample output:

[image]

I hope I didn't messed up the samples, I just came up with these for example.

Comment: Can you share sample data of your table with your desired output?

Comment: If this is your expected output, process_id = 17 is your input, please share your table data.

Comment: Hey friend I want to help you, can you just speed up your responses.

Comment: id "435" marked green, but isn't in sample output table. So what is correct?

Comment: 435 is needed. The sample output misses it, I need to change it

Comment: ok. Give me some time, I am trying

Comment: Please see ans, it is in sql server as I not aware about postgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with postgresql, so my answer is using SQL Server syntax,

```
Declare @fkProcessID int = 17
select ab.unit_id,ab.id from unit_process as a
outer apply
    (
        select top 1 * from unit_process as b
        where a.id > b.id
        order by b.id desc
    )as ab
where a.process_id = @fkProcessID
order by ab.unit_id
```

For **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1842/1)**

postgreSQL,Just missed out on variable declaration, but all else is working.

```
select ab.unit_id,ab.id from unit_process as a
 cross join LATERAL
    (
        select * from unit_process as b
        where a.id > b.id
        order by b.id desc
        LIMIT 1
    )as ab
where a.process_id = 17
order by ab.unit_id;
```

[**new DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b6b0d/8)

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I am just about to try out

Comment: Please share feedback friend.

Comment: PostgreSql doesn't like outer apply. I think there is a similiar one in postgresql, I just have to find out what it is.

Comment: +1 for the effort, I have to work on something else now for a while, but will try your solution later today. I will give you the tick if it  works

Comment: Hey Friend I have done it in postgreSQL also,please find updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for lead/lag window functions. See an experts explanation here: [How to compare the current row with next and previous row in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974866/how-to-compare-the-current-row-with-next-and-previous-row-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select p2.unit_id, p2.id
from unit_process p1
join unit_process p2 on p1.unit_id = p2.unit_id and p1.id > p2.id
where p1.process_id=17
order by p2.unit_id, p2.id
```

Comment: This would select all process steps from the unit before the specific one, yet I only need the last one before